# c# How to catch tcp keep alive packet on application

Tags: c#, networking

when I connect using TcpClient and see wire shark program, I see keep-alive packet come and go.

I want to use this for my application to know if tcp connection is alive or dead.

How do I do it?

Comment: I dont think so, I want to know what class or code I need to use to detect keep alive packet...

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate.  The answer to the other question answers your question.  If you want help with the code, then make an effort and show what you've tried.  You need to demonstrate some minimal understanding of the problem and an effort to solve it yourself.